# Unable to write oracle/SQL Query log transions data without subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 different transtions in the same table how can i join them into one line without subquerys and then joining them because i'm trying to combine multiple transtions cases if i create subquery for each transtions case and join them its causing performance issue. really appricate your help

CUREENT VIEW

```
ORDER         ACTION    DATE_TIME_CREATED
D8ZH4RJSB-689   PICK    8/1/2018 0:35
D8ZH4RJSB-689   SHIP    8/1/2018 12:03
```

Requiered Output

```
ORDER          PICK_DATE_TIME_CREATED    SHIP_DATE_TIME_CREATED
D8ZH4RJSB-689     8/1/2018 0:35            8/1/2018 12:03
```

This is my current code

```
SELECT "ORDER", --,"ACTION",ship_complete_time as date_time_created
CASE WHEN "ACTION" = 'SHIP'
THEN ship_complete_time
END AS SHIP_COM_TIME,
CASE WHEN "ACTION" = 'PICK'
THEN ship_complete_time
END AS pick_time  
FROM TRANSATIONS
WHERE "ORDER" = 'D8ZH4RJSB-689'
```

current output

```
ORDER           SHIP_COM_TIME              PICK_TIME
D8ZH4RJSB-689        (null)              2018-08-01 00:35
D8ZH4RJSB-689   2018-08-01 12:03          (null)
```

Comment: Is this oracle, or MySQL? These are 2 different database engines.

Comment: Are there cases when `TRANSACTIONS` contains data for only one of 2 actions, for any specific `ORDER` value? If so, which one would that be? How would you expect the result to look like then? Would it be an empty result (rows omitted), or just a `NULL` value in the appropriate column?

Comment: This is for Oracle.

Comment: If an order is missing a case then it would show null value.

Answer (score 3):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT "ORDER", --,"ACTION",ship_complete_time as date_time_created
       MAX(CASE WHEN "ACTION" = 'SHIP' THEN ship_complete_time END) AS SHIP_COM_TIME,
       MAX(CASE WHEN "ACTION" = 'PICK' THEN ship_complete_time END) AS pick_time  
FROM TRANSATIONS
WHERE "ORDER" = 'D8ZH4RJSB-689'
GROUP BY "ORDER";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there will be a row for picking and shipping you can do the following:

```
SELECT P.ORDER "ORDER", P.DATE_TIME_CREATED "PICK_DATE_TIME_CREATED", S.DATE_TIME_CREATED "SHIP_DATE_TIME_CREATED"
  FROM TRANSACTIONS P, TRANSACTIONS S
 WHERE P.ORDER = S.ORDER
   AND P.ACTION = 'PICK'
   AND S.ACTION = 'SHIP'
   AND P.ORDER = 'D8ZH4RJSB-689';
```

Use outer joins if you can't be sure that both rows will exist for a given order.  For performance you might also want to add an index on the columns ORDER, ACTION.

Comment: And you got empty rowset.